# Nodemailer returns nothing on sending mail

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm using nodemailer to try and get an admin to send an email, but the code I have so far returns no info or error.

The promise returns with no issue, but it's always empty.
Trying to use transporter.verify returns no info or error as well.
There are no issues with finding the admin in question.

```
var deferred = Q.defer();

Admin.findOne({username: 'admin'}, function(err, res)
{
    if(err) deferred.resolve(err);

    if(res)
    {
        var admin = _.omit(res.toJSON(), 'password');

        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
                user: 'sender@gmail.com',
                pass: "password_here"
            }
        });

        var mailOptions = {
            from: 'sender@gmail.com',
            to: 'destination@hotmail.com',
            subject: 'TEST',
            text: 'TEST',
            html: '<p> TEST EMAIL </p>'
        };

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
            if (err) deferred.reject(err);

            if(info){
                deferred.resolve(info);
            } else {
                deferred.resolve();
            }
         });
    } else {
        deferred.reject("Cannot find admin");
    }
});

return deferred.promise;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please edit the code, it looks like you have an error on mongo with 'Admin.findOne'

```
if(err) deferred.resolve(err);
```

to

```
if(err) deferred.reject(err);
```